# Неправильная ссылка на мету на странице https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Страница https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask может содержать жёлтый блок справа:

[image]

В этом блоке есть ссылка на мету (на картинке выделена стрелочкой), но она имеет неправильный адрес:

```
https://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/
```

Правильный адрес выглядит так:

```
https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Изменили ссылку на новую!